# Toggle WPF animation on button click

Tags: wpf

I want to implement the button expanding animation where when user hovers over the top button, a sneak peak of the other functions each with their own button will be displayed below that top button on which the user hovered initially. I wrote the below XAML to achieve that and it is working as expected.

XAML:

```
<Button Name="panel" Margin="0,40,0,0">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="abc">
                <Grid>
                    <Button Width="150" Name="addButton" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,10,0" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="+" Click="Button_Click">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Name="addBtn" TargetType="Button">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <TextBlock Name="addFavTxtBlock" Foreground="LightGray" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Add new task" Opacity="0" FontSize="14" Width="90" Visibility="Hidden">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Ellipse Width="30" Stroke="#00a1f1" Name="btnEllipse"
                     StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#00a1f1">
                                        </Ellipse>
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <Grid.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                        </Grid.Effect>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <!--Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                                    </-->
                                    <Trigger Property="Margin" Value="0,45,10,0">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="50" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Width="150" Name="remButton" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,10,0" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="-" Click="Button_Click">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Name="addBtn" TargetType="Button">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <TextBlock Name="remFavTxtBlock" Foreground="LightGray" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Remove task" Opacity="0" FontSize="14" Width="90" Visibility="Hidden">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Ellipse Width="30" Stroke="#00a1f1" Name="btnEllipse"
                     StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#00a1f1">
                                        </Ellipse>
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <Grid.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                        </Grid.Effect>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="50" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="Margin" Value="0,85,10,0">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="50" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Width="150" Name="editButton" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,10,0" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="..." Click="Button_Click">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Name="editBtn" TargetType="Button">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <TextBlock Name="editTxtBlock" Foreground="LightGray" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0" FontSize="14" Width="90">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Ellipse Width="30" Stroke="#00a1f1" Name="btnEllipse"
                     StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#00a1f1">
                                        </Ellipse>
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <Grid.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                        </Grid.Effect>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="editTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="editTxtBlock" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=editButton}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="enterBoard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="remButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,85,10,0" />
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="addButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,45,10,0" />
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="exitBoard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="remButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,85,10,0" />
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="addButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,45,10,0" />
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Initial Screenshot:

[image]

When the user hovers on the blue button, two additional buttons will drop from behind this blue button. It is difficult to take screenshot for that as those two buttons will be displayed only until the user is hovering on the the blue button. This is exactly my problem.

If the user wants to click on the two additional buttons which come down, the user will have to move the cursor away from the blue button and immediately these two additional buttons will go away and hide behind the blue button and thus escaping the user's click. How can I overcome this?

Is there anyway I can overwrite the Trigger.ExitActions if the user clicks on the blue button instead of hovering on it? Or any other event which I can fire up to disable the ExitActions for a while?

I am trying to create a click event for the blue button and handle the required behaviour in the code behind but if there are any other better approaches, please let me know.

Comment: Such scenarios are best handled using `VisualStates`. Use one state for `Normal` and another for `Expanded` state.

Answer (score 0):

1. Either use `VisualStates` one for `Normal` and another for `Expanded` state.
2. Or, use `ToggleButton` instead of `Button` , in case of which your code would look like this :

   ```
   <Button Name="panel" Margin="0,40,10,31">
     <Button.Template>
       <ControlTemplate x:Name="abc">
           <Grid>
               <Button Width="150" Name="addButton" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,10,0" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="+" >
                   <Button.Template>
                       <ControlTemplate x:Name="addBtn" TargetType="Button">
                           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                               <TextBlock Name="addFavTxtBlock" Foreground="LightGray" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Add new task" Opacity="0" FontSize="14" Width="90" Visibility="Hidden">
                               </TextBlock>
                               <Grid>
                                   <Ellipse Width="30" Stroke="#00a1f1" Name="btnEllipse"
               StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#00a1f1">
                                   </Ellipse>
                                   <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                   <Grid.Effect>
                                       <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                   </Grid.Effect>
                               </Grid>
                           </StackPanel>
                           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                   <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                   <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                   <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.EnterActions>
                               </Trigger>
                               <!--Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                               <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                           </-->
                               <Trigger Property="Margin" Value="0,45,10,0">
                                   <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                   <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                   <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="addFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="50" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.ExitActions>
                               </Trigger>
                           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </Button.Template>
               </Button>
               <Button Width="150" Name="remButton" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,10,0" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="-">
                   <Button.Template>
                       <ControlTemplate x:Name="addBtn" TargetType="Button">
                           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                               <TextBlock Name="remFavTxtBlock" Foreground="LightGray" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Remove task" Opacity="0" FontSize="14" Width="90" Visibility="Hidden">
                               </TextBlock>
                               <Grid>
                                   <Ellipse Width="30" Stroke="#00a1f1" Name="btnEllipse"
               StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#00a1f1">
                                   </Ellipse>
                                   <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                   <Grid.Effect>
                                       <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                   </Grid.Effect>
                               </Grid>
                           </StackPanel>
                           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                   <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                   <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                   <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                   <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="50" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.ExitActions>
                               </Trigger>
                               <Trigger Property="Margin" Value="0,85,10,0">
                                   <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                   <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                   <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="remFavTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="50" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.ExitActions>
                               </Trigger>
                           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </Button.Template>
               </Button>
               <ToggleButton Width="150" Name="editButton" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,10,0" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="...">
                   <ToggleButton.Template>
                       <ControlTemplate x:Name="editBtn" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                               <TextBlock Name="editTxtBlock" Foreground="LightGray" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0" FontSize="14" Width="90">
                               </TextBlock>
                               <Grid>
                                   <Ellipse Width="30" Stroke="#00a1f1" Name="btnEllipse"
               StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#00a1f1">
                                   </Ellipse>
                                   <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                   <Grid.Effect>
                                       <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                   </Grid.Effect>
                               </Grid>
                           </StackPanel>
                           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                   <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                   <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="btnEllipse" Value="28"></Setter>
                                   <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                       <BeginStoryboard>
                                           <Storyboard>
                                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="editTxtBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="50" Duration="00:00:00.03"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                       </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </Trigger.EnterActions>
                               </Trigger>
                               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                   <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="editTxtBlock" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                               </Trigger>
                           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </ToggleButton.Template>
               </ToggleButton>
           </Grid>
           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                      

               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=editButton}" Value="True">
                   <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                       <BeginStoryboard Name="enterBoard">
                           <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                               <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="remButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,85,10,0" />
                               </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                               <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="addButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,45,10,0" />
                               </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                           </Storyboard>
                       </BeginStoryboard>
                   </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                   <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                       <BeginStoryboard Name="exitBoard">
                           <Storyboard>
                               <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="remButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,85,10,0" />
                               </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                               <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="addButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="0,5,10,0" />
                                   <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,45,10,0" />
                               </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                           </Storyboard>
                       </BeginStoryboard>
                   </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
               </DataTrigger>

           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
   </Button>
   ```

Comment: did this work for you? I put click methods on each one of the buttons and they are not working as expected. Still behaving in the same way

Comment: @karun10 I check before posting